# node.js handle post data with content-type : application/json

Tags: node.js

Using core node.js I can handle form-data

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var body = '';
        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk.toString();
        });
        req.on('end', function() {
             var data = qs.parse(body);
             console.log(data);

        });
```

But it didn't handle application/json data properly.
The output is like that:
`{ '{"user_id":"41","url":"http://localhost:4200/#/ticket/createTicketL': '',
  'T"}': '' }`

whether the request data is :`{user_id: "41", url: "http://localhost:4200/#/ticket/createTicketL&T"}`

How to handle the data properly?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` is what you want.  I might suggest you look into Express.  It's a nice framework for making it easy to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: you can not parse the data '{"user_id":"41","url":"http://localhost:4200/#/ticket/createTicketL': '',
  'T"}': '' } . I Know about Express,but I need it in core node.js